# Infinite loop error in react useeffect when using set state

Tags: reactjs

I am facing infinite loop problem when using setstate in use effect. when i use console log it did not get infinte loop but when use setState whose value is used in map for cart state then it get infine loop. please somebody help me.

Comment: You probably have the changing value in the dependency array, e.g: inside your `useEffect` you invoke`setSomething(foo)` and in the dependency you have `[something] `.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an empty array as a second parameter... like this

```
useEffect(() => {
// your code

}, [])
```